# Finding folder & subfolder in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

- I am trying to find all `.SQL` files from my folder and it's sub folders.
- I know how to get them, but I get output like

```py
c/folder1/folder2/file.sql
```

- I want output like

```py
folder1/folder2/file.sql
```

Comment: Share your code so others can replicate and modify for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.split()`:

```
s = 'c/folder1/folder2/file.sql'
s = '/'.join(s.split('/')[1:])

print(s)
```

Output:

```
folder1/folder2/file.sql
```

---

UPDATE: More dynamic:

```
s = 'c/few folders/folder 1/folder 2/file.sql and I get output folder 1/folder 2/file.sql'
s = 'folder 1' + s.split('folder 1')[1]
```

Comment: Many Thanks Ann, I was looking for something similar.. is it possible to make this more dynamic.. example- c/few folders/folder 1/folder 2/file.sql and I get output folder 1/folder 2/file.sql

Comment: @shubhamgarg Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard library, in particular [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) and the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method, like this:

```py
import pathlib
parent = pathlib.Path(path_to_parent_directory)
sql_paths = sorted(parent.glob("**/*.SQL"))
```

To get the relative paths and the strings:

```
relative_paths = [p.relative_to(parent) for p in sql_paths]
```

You can keep working with these path objects, or you can convert them to strings with the `as_posix` method: `[p.as_posix() for p in relative_paths]`.

Comment: Thanks mate .. I will try this